# $_SESSIONS multiple unwanted sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies, httponly

I've been having trouble with a session-based login website where ive found multiple sessions for my site; one or two www.domain.com session files and mine, a simple domain.com session.
All the sessions have different session_ids. Causing unnecessary logouts. All of this seemed to work just fine but I think my php version changed and opened up a world of hurt.

I have two fixes so far.

> ## 1.
>
> In the actual php code before each session_start()
>   ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly', 1 );

also

> ## 2.
>
> in my php.ini:
>
> void session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool >$secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]] )

With a combination of these actions I had three session cookies, only a session cookie starting with www, which was the wrong session_id.

And now more tragically no session cookies visible, although they are present somewhere because i can call the  print_r($_SESSION); and see cookie data sotred, but it's not showing up in my browser.

Please, any advice?

Comment: Are you regenerating your session ids using session_regenerate ?

Comment: No I was not using sessionregenerate. Well I found a way around the issue. I changed my .htaccess redirect so that whenever my page loaded as www.domain.com it redirected to http://domain.com dierctly.  I'm not sure how this will hold long term, but now its not creating a session for www.domain.com